# How does this follow from the definition of a stalk?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ a presheaf on $X$. The stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $x$ is defined as $$\mathcal{F}_x = \varinjlim_{x\in U} \mathcal{F}(U)$$

In some books I read, that this is equivalent to $\mathcal{F}_x$ being the set of equivalence classes of pairs $(U,s)$ where $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ and $s\in \mathcal{F}(U)$ with the equivalence relation $(U_1,s_1) \sim (U_2,s_s)$ if and only if there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ with $V\subset U_1 \cap U_2$ such that $s_1|_V = s_2|_V$.

Why are these definitions equivalent? I know what the definition of the colimit is, but I experience it as difficult to handle. What is a good source to understand limits and colimits better?

Comment: The equivalence you are looking for is just the definition of direct limit. To handle it, try to understand which is the direct set you are using to define the stalk: once you've got it then it should be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you speak German, Martin Brandenburg has written an excellent introductory book on category theory. Otherwise, I recommend the handbook of categorical algebra by Borceux. Ultimately, even the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) is quite useful, tho.

Let us define $\mathscr F_x$ as the set of equivalence classes you describe and check that this object satisfies the universal property. First, we have morphisms $F_U\colon\mathscr F(U)\to \mathscr F_x$ by mapping $f\in\mathscr F(U)$ to the equivalence class of $(U,f)$, which I will therefore just denote by $F_U(f)$. I will denote the restriction by $R_{VU}\colon\mathscr F(U)\to\mathscr F(V)$ for $x\in V\subseteq U$. Indeed, assume that there is some object $\mathscr G$ and morphisms $G_U\colon \mathscr F(U)\to\mathscr G$ with the property that for $x\in V\subseteq U$, we have $G_U=G_V\circ R_{VU}$.

Then, we define a map $H\colon \mathscr F_x\to\mathscr G$ by decreeing that $H(F_U(f))=G_U(f)$. We first check that it is well-defined: If $F_{U_1}(f_1)=F_{U_2}(f_2)$  then there is a $x\in V\subseteq U_1\cap U_2$ with $R_{VU_1}(f_1)=R_{VU_2}(f_2)$. Hence, 
$$
H(F_{U_1}(f_1))=H(F_V(R_{VU_1}(f_1)))=H(F_V(R_{VU_2}(f_2)))=H(F_{U_2}(f_2))
$$
so $H$ is well-defined as a map. Depending on what kind of category your sheaf takes values in, you need to check that it also preserves structure. It is clear that we have defined $H$ in the only way possible to achieve $H\circ F_U = G_U$ for all open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$.

This verifies that $\mathscr F_x$ has the universal property of the direct limit, therefore it is one.